# Set CSS style for child nodes in style attribute

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to set children nodes's styles from within the style of a parent without using the <style> element in <head>?

E.g. I have a table where I have a row (first row below), and I want all text in the TD elements to be font size 7pt.

Something like:

```
  <table>
    <tr style='font-size:7pt;'>  <--- How do I tell it to apply to child TD elements
      <td>cell 1 should be formatted to 7pt font</td>
      <td>cell 2 should be formatted to 7pt font</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>cell without format</td>
      <td>another cell without format</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Thanks,
Grant

Comment: What you have should work. If it doesn't there must be other CSS interfering.

Comment: The code you've written does exactly what you asked. I don't understand the question.

Comment: So [your posted code works](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7qKbK/), though I added a `style` tag to the parent `table` element, just to make it profoundly visible that it works.

Comment: @thirtydot It works, because font-size is inherited, it won't work with styles that are not being inherited naturally.

Comment: @Christoph: Well, only `font-size` was mentioned. If there could be other properties (that aren't inheritable), the example given in the question is a bad one.

Answer (score 3):

```
<table>
<tr class="format">
  <td>cell 1 should be formatted to 7pt font</td>
  <td>cell 2 should be formatted to 7pt font</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>cell without format</td>
  <td>another cell without format</td>
</tr>
```

```
<style>.format>td{font-size:7pt;}</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with declaring a `scoped` style like following:

```
  <table>
    <tr>
    <style scoped>  <--- "scoped" tells the browser to apply the styles inside the tr
        {your-selector}{             
            {styles}
        }
    </style>
      <td>cell 1 should be formatted to 7pt font</td>
      <td>cell 2 should be formatted to 7pt font</td>
    </tr>
    ...
  </table>
```

However, Browsersupport for this is terrible atm.

Read the [Article on Html5Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/the-scoped-attribute/) it is really interesting, and there exists a polyfill, you can use until the browsers support it.

edit:

Up to date FF, Chrome and Opera seem to support it now: [Article on HTML5Rocks](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/03/A-New-Experimental-Feature-style-scoped)

Comment: You still need to use rules. `<style scoped>font-size:7pt;</style>` won't work, you need `<style scoped>td{font-size:7pt;}</style>`.

Comment: @thirtydot yes of course, thanks for pointing this out. Wrote it in a more generic way now. I think the OP knows how to write styles;)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it for child elements.

The style attribute specifies an inline style for an element. ([source](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_style.asp))

You can use jQuery to do what you want:

```
<script>
$("tr:first-child td").attr("style", "font-size:7pt");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible directly. but if you still want to use inline style then you need to use JavaScript and set style for each element. again it not a good solution

valid way is --> following will work in IE7 and UP & all other browsers

```
<style>
table tr:first-child > td {font-size:7pt;}
</style>
```

You probably want to give class name to your table.

Comment: He specified that he did not want to use the `<style>` tag

Comment: yes i understand. and so suggested to add style using javascript but gave proper way as well.

Answer (score -2):

No it's not, this is exactly what the style tag is for :-) By the way try to avoid inline style.